# Push element value from array of objects to a variable

Tags: javascript

I have some data from a collection named "service" which has data like this:

```
let service_data = [
  {
    "name":"Service 1",
    "price":60,
    "resource_group_ids" : 
         ["5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f78dcd","5d5e85d329782914332368c8"]
  },
  {
    "name":"Service 2",
    "price":60,
    "resource_group_ids" : ["5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f7cfe"]
  }
]
```

I want to push the resource_group_ids in a variable let say resource_groups. I don't want to loop resource_group_ids inside service_data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with `.map()`, `.join()` and `.split()`

```js
    const service_data = [
      {
        name: 'Service 1',
        price: 60,
        resource_group_ids:
          ['5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f78dcd', '5d5e85d329782914332368c8']
      },
      {
        name: 'Service 2',
        price: 60,
        resource_group_ids: ['5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f7cfe']
      },
    ];
    
    const result = service_data.map((r) => { return r.resource_group_ids; 
               }).join(',').split(',');
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```
const resource_groups = service_data.flatMap(o => o.resource_group_ids)
```

```js
const service_data = [{"name":"Service 1","price":60,"resource_group_ids":["5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f78dcd","5d5e85d329782914332368c8"]},{"name":"Service 2","price":60,"resource_group_ids":["5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f7cfe"]}]

const resource_groups = service_data.flatMap(o => o.resource_group_ids)

console.log(resource_groups)
```

If `flatMap` is not supported, use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge the 2D array returned by `map`

```
const resource_groups = [].concat(...service_data.map(o=> o.resource_group_ids))
```

Comment: Note that flatMap only works in the node 12 release line.

Comment: @AyushGupta added an alternative

Answer (score 3):

You can use flatMap

```js
const extractFlat = (arr, key) => {
    return arr.flatMap(e => e[key]);
};

let service_data = [
  {
    "name":"Service 1",
    "price":60,
    "resource_group_ids" : 
         ["5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f78dcd","5d5e85d329782914332368c8"]
  },
  {
    "name":"Service 2",
    "price":60,
    "resource_group_ids" : ["5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f7cfe"]
  }
]

const resource_group_ids = extractFlat(service_data, 'resource_group_ids');
console.log(resource_group_ids);
```

or reduce on older environments

```
const extractFlat = (arr, key) => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x[key]), []);
};
```

Comment: Will this work in ie6? (*squeezes eyes from curiosity*)

Comment: Nothing works in ie6, but it's 2019 so that's not too big of a problem any more

Comment: @chrispbacon I am getting resource_groups : undefined on console.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.reduce`:

```js
let service_data = [{
    "name": "Service 1",
    "price": 60,
    "resource_group_ids": ["5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f78dcd", "5d5e85d329782914332368c8"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Service 2",
    "price": 60,
    "resource_group_ids": ["5d5e5dea99d9b75ff2f7cfe"]
  }
]

const resource_groups = service_data.reduce(function(result, item) {
  result.concat(item.resource_group_ids)
}, [])

console.log(resource_groups)
```